# how set focus in angular md-autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have a dialog with few field to set, the first field is a `md-autocomplete`, when I click ok all these fields are cleaned, so, I want set focus true in the `md-autocomplete`, for starting to filling data again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this :

**JS:**

```js
$scope.setFocus = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('#autoCompleteId').focus();
  }, 0);
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<md-autocomplete .............. md-input-id="autoCompleteId">
  <!-- Note the id -->
</md-autocomplete>

<input type="button" value="clickMeForFocus" ng-click="setFocus()" />
```

The timeout is needed to make sure that the autocomplete component is rendered at the time of calling focus.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by adding attribute

> md-autofocus

an example:

```
<md-autocomplete md-autofocus md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display">
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

ref : [here](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.4/api/directive/mdAutofocus)

Regards.

Comment: That works for first time that dialog is opened, when click ok, and data are cleaned, focus is lost and md-autofocus does not work. I have this solution, when dialog is hidden, I call this document.getElementById('product-name-input').querySelector('input').focus();